# Bash - some commands don't display quotation marks correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm ssh'ing into a remote server (using bash). Some commands (e.g. `cp`, `rm`, etc.) display quotations incorrectly:

```
$ rm ./test
rm: remove regular file â€˜./test€™?
```

Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check your locale environment variables with `printenv | grep LC_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export LANG=C
```

I guess the issue is that your workstation has some localized LANG which is passed to the environment on server, but the server does not understand it properly.